# 404 Database error on MAMP WordPress install

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress, mamp

I am struggling to finish the local installation of Wordpress on MAC. I used MAMP and migrated all the files successfully: database on PhpAdmin and wp-config.php & wp-content.php via FileZilla. I get a database connection issue when trying to access the site.

I followed the instructions of this guy:
https://hsnyc.co/how-to-transfer-a-live-wordpress-website-to-your-localhost-manually/
except that I use MAMP and the localhost is Macintosh> Applications>MAMP>htdocs (The Database is under htdocs)

Tools used on a MAC Book Pro:
MAMP
PhpAdmin
FileZilla
Interconnect It
Wordpress
The PHP version used is 7.0.0.

Note: the Database name Is made of capital and small letters no space.

I changed the Database credentials in wp.config.php to the below:

```
define('WP_HOME','http://localhost/DataBaseName');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://localhost/ DataBaseName ');

// ** MySQL settings - You can get this info from your web host ** //
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define('DB_NAME', 'DataBaseName');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'root');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'root');

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
```

I also get a 404 error message when clicking on "localhost:3306" tab in PhpAdmin.

Solutions tried:

- I reviewed the DataBase credentials
- I tried changing the Localhost to "localhost:3306", " 127.0.0.1", " 127.0.0.1:3306".

Note: at first, I entered the wrong database name and got a message that the database couldn't be found.

Comment: Can you try to rename root `.htaccess` file for a moment and check again ?

Comment: What do you mean rename root .htaccess? How would i do that?

Comment: Take backup of `.htaccess` file, delete it, test it.